# Which would be the best switch for a cloud cluster?

Tags: networking, switch, cloud

I am about to set up a private cloud using Eucalyputs on CentOS, and I am confused about buying a network switch. Right now there will be 4 node controllers on my cloud, but in the near future I am planning to add more nodes to it.

So I am interested in know which switch I should I opt for, whether a managed switch or an unmanaged switch. Which would be the better option to go for?

Comment: Better how? This question is too vague and won't result in good answers, only arguments over which better is better.

Comment: @DrewKhoury I dunno, this particular question only has one possible answer.

Comment: The rationale for the close votes is invalid. I happened to suggest a particular model of hardware, but the question and the primary part of my answer were about general infrastructure principles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You absolutely want a managed switch so that you can monitor reliability and performance; expanded management features such as VLANs and LACP may not be needed now but are very helpful to have available. Most basic managed layer-2 switches should be fine for your needs. Cisco has become rather unfriendly with their feature licensing on fixed-port switches, and I would recommend looking at an HP 24-port gigabit switch such as the 2810-24G.

Comment: Hi @Chrylis, thanks for your suggestion, that was really helpful.